# I can't seem to figure out how to debug my TFS 2010 Build

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, tfsbuild

I am trying to figure out how to debug in VS using the TFSBuildServiceHost.exe method, here is the article about this: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/baruchf/archive/2009/07/02/debugging-team-build-now-you-can.aspx

I am not able to get this working. First off, my machine does not have a  TFSBuildServiceHost.exe running. So I tried to do this on my team foundation build server and I found the process. Great so I open the workingflow script, set my breakpoint, attach the process. Then what? The article says "Run the build." How? There is no run button...

So instead I went to my team explorer and right clicked the build and run it, but the breakpoint does not get hit. What am I missing?

If I look on the breakpoint window I see my breakpoint but it has a warning symbol that says "this breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

Could this have something to do with the fact that I am using the method where I have an "ActivityPack" project and I have branched the build script into a directory in this project. I have pointed the team explorer to this branched build script.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your Output window while you are attached to TFSBuildServiceHost.exe. Do you have a line like this

> Instrumentation for debugger fails.  Reason: Could not find file 'c:\blah\blah\blah\BuildProcessTemplates\MyBuildTemplate.xaml'..'TFSBuildServiceHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Workflow'

The build template file records the path to itself inside the file. Open up your build process template file in a text editor. Look for a `XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName` attribute within. If the value of that attribute doesn't match the actual file location of the xaml file you had open when you were setting breakpoints, the debugger will not be able to hit those breakpoints.